# swift syntax confusion dispatchqueue async

Tags: swift, asynchronous

Hello I was reading about dispatch queues and GDC in swift, here is the article:

https://swiftable.io/2016/06/dispatch-queues-swift-3/

I had a question regarding the syntax when calling the async method in the examples.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print("main thread dispatch")
}
```

According to the apple docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue

async is a DispatchQueue instance method.  Is async passing in a closure function in the above syntax?  I am not familiar with this specific block {} syntax being used for async.

Comment: It is a trailing closure as described in the Swift book from Apple

Comment: Specifically, here is the link in the Swift book to [Trailing Closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID94)